# HTTPs method VS Web socket

Tags: post, https, websocket

after some reasearch
knowing websocket is lighter than https method post and get
however in term of security, post is more secure than websocket.
as i could still use web socket even my server restart(logged out)

in this case, i found that i couldnt check if that particular user is authenticated user or not.
or maybe im wrong.
please correct me.

im using express js and https and i had done some action using https post.
(in here socket automatically using secure connection as https) but the problem is authentication

so my question here is.
i want to turn them into websocket as its lighter.
can web socket check if the one sending is authenticated and session is still active(e.g logged out user cant emit)?

or should i stick with https post?

if there is a way to authenticate emitted socket(from client to server)... please share with me here

thanks alot

Comment: You can implement authentication over websocket in pretty much the same way you do over http: by sending tokens. You just have to serialize in/out data differently. Ws also gives you other authentication mechanisms that are not available over http due to the fact that ws is stateful, unlike http. E.g. authenticate once and make the server remember that this connection is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing another authentication, 
i had found something nice here and its works.

https://www.codementor.io/tips/0217388244/sharing-passport-js-sessions-with-both-express-and-socket-io

i could use existing passport authentication on my socket

note: since im using mongodb
then i do not use radis.. instead i use mongostore for the session store from npm connect-mongo

hope this will help other